# How do I know a gmail account is a member of Google Groups?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-groups

I am creating a web app with Google Apps Script.
I want to know if an app user is a member of Google Groups.

Group site: https://groups.google.com/

It is not groups managed by G suite.

Create a Google spreadsheet. 
Open this and add the group's email in the sharing task.

When I open a file shared by a group in a script and open it, can I verify that it is a member of the group?

Comment: I want to qualify only members of the Google Group to be members of the Google Team Drive.

Comment: How will you access the list of users in a group? If the group is not in G-suite are you the owner of the group?

Comment: I am the owner of the group.
But it does not matter.
I need a way to know the members of a group in the webapp.

Here are the scenarios:
I create a spreadsheet file on Google Drive.
Then invite the group to view this file.
I can find the group members by adding code to open the file in the Script Editor.

Answer (score 0):

What's available from Google's API is the [Members.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/list).

Retrieves a paginated list of all members in a group.

Give it a [try](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/list#try-it).

Haven't really tried it but the Apps Script version seems to be [getUsers()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/groups/group#getusers).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible. This is information you would have to get when the script executes. When the script runs, the Active User (`Session.getActiveUser()`) is the script owner (you), and the user returned by `Session.getEffectiveUser()` won't allow you to get the email address. More information at:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user#getemail

Basically, this would only work on a G Suite domain.